# JustHost.com and Python CGI

Tags: python

I'm trying to get justhost.com to compile a python CGI script (helloworld.py)  without much luck.  The site says python works, but I can't find much.

I'm using http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_tutorial

Has anyone gotten it to work?

Comment: Needs more detail: what step in the tutorial is not working?  what does "not working" mean?  is there anything in the logs?

Comment: lemme work on it for a few minutes.  Just found some good information

Comment: got it, and posted answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

for justhost.com users you must do a few things.

- set up a directory in 'public_html/'
  called 'scgi-bin/'
- go to your control panel and the
  'advanced options'  -> 'Apache
  Handlers' -> now add a user defined
  apache handler ( handler: cgi-script,
  extenstion: .py) and 'add.'
- write your helloworld.py (http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_hello_world)
- upload this to the 'scgi-bin/' folder
  earlier created. (beware: must be
  uploaded in ascii format. 
  Dreamweaver apparently uses binary as
  default, i used filezille (set
  transfer mode to ascii)
- run! www.yoursite.com/scgi-bin/helloworld.py

Comment: I had to move my hello.py file form scgi-bin directory to cgi-bin and then it worked. 
If you run your script from 'scgi-bin' directory you'll get :
'scgiwrap: Caller must be the nobody user' error.