# How to expose Django/Python application to the web?

Tags: python, django, web

I developed a simple Django/Python poll application(Following step by step tutorial from the Django Official Documentation). I used the in build server to test the application. Now, I want to host my application in the web. I heard WSGI is the best way to expose Python/Django application to the web? What would be the best way to expose Python/Django code into the web? Thank you

P.S: I already have a domain name and a shared web hosting from justhost.com. While I chat to their support, they told me that they support WSGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a HTTP server program like Apache or NGINX to serve your http requests. There will be a module like fastCGI or the better WSGI to interact with your python scripts/environment. These HTTP server programs and databases will be on a web host machine that you can rent that also provides static IPs and domain name resolution. For Django I can highly recommend [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/), they support it and have good [documentation](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html). You will probably also need to register a domain name via a registrar if you dont want to use the sample subdomain provided by your web host.

**Update:** for justhost, see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3970821/1086804).

Comment: I have a domain name and a shared hosting from justhost. While I talked to their support, they told me that the shared hosting support wsgi too.

Comment: One more question? To web expose Python/Django do I need to add something in my code like import wsgi library or something like that? THank you for your answer.

Comment: Yea, that's helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for [Heroku](http://heroku.com). They have a free usage quota, and a really nice deployment mechanism. Here's a nice article describing how to use it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Comment: Heroku, no doubt, is a good PaaS. I usually recommend OpenSource to developers and users. Here is OpenShift, an open source PaaS by Red Hat.

  https://openshift.redhat.com/

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do that is to find a host online (such as pythonanywhere.com) to host your app on there, following their instructions, and your app will be online.  They handle most of the issues with piggybacking a django project on a server.

Answer (score 2):

The [deployment how to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/) in the documentation lists supported ways to deploy django.